# How to Gaussian processes for time series prediction?

Tags: normal-distribution, prediction

I am trying to fit Gaussian process to learn a distribution from input sequence to output sequence. I am relatively new and have several questions:

1) For time series prediction problems, if you have a sequential input you can feed them without stacking inputs into a vector while using RNNs or LSTMs. Do Gaussian processes have such a structure? If no, is it still make sense to use GPs to learn output sequence from input sequence?

2) When I try to fit GP to training data with 400 samples and 18 features it has really difficult time. Is there a way to batch the data and use the learned parameters from one batch to another as in neural networks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This paper below shows that you can model sequenced data using Gaussian processes. It also contains a good introduction on applying GPs to time series data.

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~sjrob/Pubs/philTransA_2012.pdf

In terms of modeling input sequence to output sequences, the most best modeling framework as per Andrew Ng is Attention Models.